# Understanding char & and const

Tags: c++, char, constants

I am learning C++ and have trouble understanding some concepts. In the following program, (1) why did it use `char&` instead of `char`, I think it should use just a `char`, because the member function returns `text[position]` and this is a `char` type, not a reference. (2) In `const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const`, why the second `const` is necessary? I tried to delete it and keep only the first `const`, but it reported error. Thank you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
class TextBook{
        public:
                TextBook(std::string s)
                {
                        text.assign(s);
                }
                const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const {
                        return text[position];
                }
                char& operator[](std::size_t position){
                        return text[position];
                }
        private:
                std::string text;
};

int main()
{
        const TextBook ctb("Hello");
        std::cout << ctb[0] << std::endl;
        TextBook tb("Morning");
        tb[2]='M';
        std::cout << tb[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `test[position]` *is* a reference to `char` (or `const char` depending on which one you meant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: When I refer to "first" and "second", I'm referring to the non-const and const versions, respectively.

In the first situation, it's necessary to return a reference in the case that the caller wished to modify the string. By returning a reference to a character in the string, calls like this:

```
book[index] = 'a';
```

will actually modify the underlying string itself, as the operator would have returned a reference to the actual character in the string, rather than a copy of the character at the index.

In the second example, we need do two things. We are creating another operator[] for use with const objects. This operator is different. As you noted, there is a const following the method declaration. This means that when operator[] is used on a const object, this operator will be called instead of the non-const version.

The const version returns a const reference, which makes code like this impossible if  `book` is const:

```
book[index] = 'a';
```

If `book` were const, this would call the second `operator[]` and would return a const reference. Since const references cannot be changed, we've essentially prevented the modification of const books through the use of `operator[]`

Comment: Thank you. in const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const {}, can I write it as const char& operator[](std::size_t position) {} ? (don't have the second const? )

Comment: @daydayup You can't do that, because then you will have two non-const operators. The compiler will not know which operator to use on your non-const object. You need to add the `const` at the end of the operator. It tells the compiler that this is the operator that should be used for `const` objects. This ensures that a const reference is returned for const objects (non-modifiable), and a non-const reference is returned for non-const objects (modifiable). That way, we can change the string of a non-const object, and we can't change the string of a const object.

Answer (score 1):

1) The point of the function is to return a reference to a character. If it just returned the value, the code in `main` wouldn't work as it would change just the returned value.

2) The point of these two functions is to allow `tb[2]` to work on either a const or non-const `TextBook`. On a non-const object, it returns a non-const reference. On a const object, it returns a const reference.

Comment: Thank you. in const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const {}, can I write it as const char& operator[](std::size_t position) {} ? (don't have the second const? )

Comment: @daydayup What would the point be? If it's not a const member function, what does it do that the other function doesn't?